# How shape Tensor array?

Tags: tensorflow

I have lately been vexed by the following error message:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2455040,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(2455040, ?)'
```

Which is being produced from running the following code:

```
NUMCLASSES=16
NUMPIXELS=959*640*4
# set up to feed an array of images [images, size_of_image]
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [NUMPIXELS,None])
```

....deletia....

```
# Define loss and optimizer..why is this 2d?
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,NUMCLASSES])


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run(session=sess)
tl = get_tensor_list()

for f, n in tl:
    str = '/users/me/downloads/train/' + f
    mm = Image.open(str)
    mm = mm.convert('F')
    mma=np.array(mm)
    i = mma.flatten() #now this is an array of floats of size NUMPIXELS 
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: i, y_: n})  # <<DEATH
```

Somehow, that array is getting a shape that tf does not like [(x,) when it wants (x,?)]. How to satisfy the tensorgods in this case? The tensor must be what it must be for other mathematical reasons not discussed.

Comment: Please consider writing the questions clearly. Your example code is also vague.

Comment: I will try again: I declare a tensor of shape [NUMPIXELS, None], and get an image of shape [ROWPIX,COLPIX] which I flatten into [NUMPIXELS,], which chokes when I pass it to sess.run(). I suppose the questions are: (1) how to coerce the shape of the image to [NUMPIXELS]; (2) why is shape [NUMPIXELS,] not good enough when the tensor is [NUMPIXELS,None(==?)] ?

Answer (score 0):

reshaping the array might help.

```
i = mma.flatten().reshape((NUMPIXELS,1))
```

Comment: Been there, did that, got the T-shirt. No joy: (NUMPIXELS,<nothing>) .

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the two tensors have different [ranks](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/tensors): tensor with shape (2455040,) has rank 1, while tensor with shape (2455040,?) has rank 2.

You can do this:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
x = tf.reshape(x, [NUMPIXELS,-1])
```